# Why is my Perl script not using all CPU cores?

Tags: perl

Apparently the script only utilizes one CPU core, while the machine has four. Is it my code or some other setting? I am new to Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Queue;
use DBI();
use File::Touch;

my $databasefile = "/var/www/deamon/new.db";
my $count        = touch($databasefile);

my $dbuser        = "****";
my $dbpwd         = "****";
my $dbhost        = "localhost";
my $dbname        = "****";
my $max_threads   = 16;
my $queue_id_list = Thread::Queue->new;
my @childs;

#feeds entries to the queue list
my $ArrayMonitor = threads->new(\&URLArrayMonitor, $queue_id_list);
sleep 3;    #make sure system has enough time to connect and load up array

#start 10 crawler threads (these are the work horses)
my $CrawlerThreads = ();
for (0 .. $max_threads) {
    $CrawlerThreads->[$_] = threads->new(\&NameChecker, $queue_id_list);

    #print "Crawler " . ($_ + 1) . " created.\n";
}

#print "Letting threads run until queue is empty.\n";

while ($queue_id_list->pending > 0) {
    sleep .01;
}

sleep 1;

foreach my $thr (threads->list) {

    # don't join the main or ourselves
    if ($thr->tid && !threads::equal($thr, threads->self)) {

        #print "Waiting for thread " . $thr->tid . " to join\n";
        #print "Thread " . $thr->join . " has joined.\n";
        sleep .01;
    }
}

sub URLArrayMonitor {
    my ($queue_id_list) = @_;

    #**********************************************
    # here we walk though all users / select database and check what needs to be checked
    #**********************************************
    my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=" . $dbname . ";host=" . $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, {'RaiseError' => 1});
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM ci_users WHERE user_group >= 10 ORDER BY user_id");
    $sth->execute();
    while (my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {

        # now we check the user if there are names we need to check
        print "Now checking relian_user_" . $ref->{'user_id'} . "\r\n";
        eval {
            my $dbuser
              = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=user_" . $ref->{'user_id'} . ";host=" . $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, {'RaiseError' => 1});
            my $stuser = $dbuser->prepare("SELECT * FROM ci_address_book WHERE lastchecked=0");    #select only new
            $stuser->execute();
            while (my $entry = $stuser->fetchrow_hashref()) {
                my @queueitem = ($ref->{'user_id'} . "#" . $entry->{'id'});
                $queue_id_list->enqueue(@queueitem);
            }
            $stuser->finish();
            $dbuser->disconnect();
        };
        warn "failed to connect - $dbuser->errstr" if ($@);
    }
    $sth->finish();
    $dbh->disconnect();
    print "List now contains " . $queue_id_list->pending . " records.\n";
    sleep 1;
}

sub NameChecker {
    my ($queue_id_list) = @_;
    while ($queue_id_list->pending > 0) {
        my $info = $queue_id_list->dequeue_nb;
        if (defined($info)) {
            my @details      = split(/#/, $info);
            my $result       = system("/var/www/deamon/NewScan/match_name db=" . $details[0] . " id=" . $details[1]);
            my $databasefile = "/var/www/deamon/new.db";
            my $count        = touch($databasefile);

            #print "Thread: ". threads->self->tid. " - Done user: ".$details[0]. " and addressbook id: ". $details[1]."\r\n";
            #print $queue_id_list->pending."\r\n";
        }
    }

    #print "Crawler " . threads->self->tid . " ready to exit.\n";

    return threads->self->tid;
}
```

Comment: What OS/version of Perl are you running? Just paste the output of `perl -v`

Comment: [use forks;](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?forks)

Comment: When this link dies the question will become worthless, but still turn up in google searches.

Comment: This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 40 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
I am sorry, i tried to put the code in but it was all messy... Using Ubuntu for develop, but the server in question is running Redhat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tasks you are performing in each thread don't look that CPU intensive. Are they? The `&URLArrayMonitor` uses database resources, but that won't use a lot of CPU unless the database is on the same machine as the Perl script. I can't tell what resources the external program in `&NameChecker` is likely to use, but based on your comments it looks like it may use a lot of network bandwidth; again not a lot of CPU. So you shouldn't be too surprised if you can run this script on a single core.

If you want to test whether multi-threaded programs are using multiple cores, try giving it a CPU-intensive task:

```
use threads;
use Math::BigInt;
threads->new(sub {print new Math::BigInt($_[0])->bfac()}, 400000) for 1..10;
print `uptime` while sleep 5;
```

Comment: actually the external script it calls will grab the cpu full as that script is really intensive on database queries. I programmed it on my local machine which is ubuntu and I could have sworn it was using multi cores, then put it in the server where it should go and the administrator said it's only using 1cpu. I am going to try your test script and see what happens... let you know...thank you!

Comment: Mob, you are actually right, my script doesn't get to doo that, it is in the end MYSQLD which takes 100% CPU, as it is doing levenshtein calculations. So I think my threading script works as it should. Now I need to find a way to get rid of that levenshtein module...